# Joining values with DateDim, where null'd dates' value will take the last non-null value in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to do a join but I'm not sure which type.  I have a table like this:

```
Date        Amount | FOO
------------------
2012-01-12       x
2012-03-14       y
2012-05-06       z
2012-05-14      aa
2012-09-02      bb
```

I am joining this with DateDim (Google here: [DATE DIM](http://www.google.com/search?q=datedim+sql), which is a table of dates (historical and future).

I need a query that would display data like this:

```
datedim.Date    foo.Amount | FOO x DATEDIM
------------------------------------------
2012-01-12               x
2012-01-13               x
2012-01-14               x
... etc...
2012-03-14               y
2012-03-15               y
2012-03-16               y
2012-03-17               y
... etc...
2012-05-06               z
... etc...
```

Basically, I need the values to persist (were it a left join, it would be NULLs) until the next non-null value.  That will persist too... etc..

---

What I have so far...

```
SELECT datedim.Date
    ,CASE
        WHEN Amount IS NULL
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Amount
        FROM FOO WHERE foo.Date <= datedim.Date
        ORDER BY Date DESC)
        ELSE Amount END AS Amount
FROM DATEDIM datedim
LEFT JOIN FOO foo
ON foo.Date = datedim.Date
```

I need to create a view out of this.  I'm getting an error saying ORDER BY is invalid for views, unless specified by TOP???  I do have a TOP in the subquery...

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Certain ones may have better functions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ use recursive CTE

```
;WITH cte (id, [Date], Amount) AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS id,
         [Date], Amount
  FROM dbo.your_table t1
  ), cte2 (id, [Date], [LevelDate], Amount) AS
 (         
  SELECT c1.id, c1.[Date], DATEDIFF(day, c1.[Date], c2.[Date]) AS [LevelDate], c1.Amount
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.id = c2.id - 1
  ), cte3 (id, [Date], Amount, [Level]) AS
 (
  SELECT  id, [Date], Amount, 1 AS [Level]
  FROM cte2 c
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, DATEADD(day, 1, ct.[Date]) AS [Date], c.Amount, ct.[Level] + 1
  FROM cte2 c JOIN cte3 ct ON c.id = ct.id
  WHERE c.[LevelDate] > ct.[Level]
  )
  SELECT [Date], Amount
  FROM cte3
  ORDER BY Date
  OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/425a7/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more efficient ways using a CTE, or window functions, but something along these lines should work:

```
Select
  d.Date,
  d.FooDate,
  f.Amount
From
  Foo f
    Inner Join (
    Select
      d.[Date],
      Max(f.[Date]) as FooDate
    From
      Foo f
       Inner Join
      DateDim d
        On f.[Date] < d.[Date]
    Group By
      d.[Date]
  ) d 
  On d.[FooDate] = f.[Date]
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c7d5/10

Comment: Thanks.  It's not quite what I was looking for.  See update in the OP.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What happened to March 1 in DateDim in your SQLfiddle?

Comment: Your example doesn't have any data before your first date in Foo? I assumed you didn't want to see it?